# Как по отдельности скопировать текст из строки Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот примерная строка [www.google.com/12345/kOlsafWW](http://www.google.com/12345/kOlsafWW)

Но цифры 12345 всегда разные и kOlsafWW тоже размер тоже.

Как по отдельности изъять текст 12345 и kOlsafWW в Python.

Comment: Не понятно. Ссылка с которой копируете статичная? Вы можете просто брать эту ссылку и использовать `split` и забирать два последних значения. 
А если динамическая то искать ссылку в каком то месте где она меняется и проворачивать ту же операцию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно не совсем правильно понял вопрос. Но предложу такой вариант.

Случай первый когда в строке разделители только `/`

```
url = 'www.google.com/12345/kOlsafWW'
url_split = url.split('/')

elem1 = url_split[-1]
elem2 = url_split[-2]

print (elem1, elem2)
```

---

Случай если в строке есть разделитель `?` то в этом случаи мы заменяем его на `/`

```
url = 'www.google.com?12345/kOlsafWW'
url_replace = url.replace('?', '/')
url_split = url_replace.split('/')

elem1 = url_split[-1]
elem2 = url_split[-2]

print (elem1, elem2)
```

Comment: Можно так `*_, elem2, elem1 = 'www.google.com/12345/kOlsafWW'.split("/")` Если слэша на конце нет

Comment: А если ссылка www.google.com?12345/kOlsafWW то как обрезать 12345 если он в ? и /

Comment: @Опача обновил ответ